# Month name from date column

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a column  with date format, this kind of columns usually have a hierarchy with day, month and year to filter by but I'm using a direct query from my database and this doesn't appear.

I've tried to split columns but when I try to split a column by name month this returns me an error because this kind of action is not compatible with a direct query.

Then I thought that one way to solve my problem as I can't do changes in columns it could be to make a Dax Function that extract month and year from my column

This is the Column I'm talking about:
[image: Column Date]
This is the error when i try split columns by delimiter:
[image: Error in DirectQuery]

I've tried with MONTH function but this retuns me an error:
[image: Error]

Comment: Have you tried using YEAR, MONTH, DAY functions, or FORMAT to create calculated columns in DAX?

Comment: Comment of @OscarLar is useful: When you need it for calculations, you need to use MONTH & YEAR. When you only want to show it to end user, you can use FORMAT.

Answer (score 3):

In DirectQuery mode, there's also a number of restrictions to the DAX functions available. For example, the [FORMAT](https://dax.guide/format/) function does not work within a calculated column. However, the [MONTH](https://dax.guide/month), [YEAR](https://dax.guide/year) and [DAY](https://dax.guide/day) functions work just fine, so in order to create a column with the month names, you could use this:

```
SWITCH ( MONTH ( [FechaAuditoria] ),
    1 , "January" ,
    2 , "February" ,
    3 , "March" ,
    ...
)
```

Comment: MONTH Function does not let me use a entire column, it retuns me an error

Comment: Looking at the error message shown in your post, are you sure you're adding the formula with MONTH as a CALCULATED COLUMN to the same table that holds the [FechaAuditoria] column?